# mongodb rank and get most chosen

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following datas in my collection.

```
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d7",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d8",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d8",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d7",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d8",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d2",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
{votedid:"60dc516f44b8d2c02be2e6d1",voter:"bla bla bla - doesn't matter"}
```

I need to rank those datas depending on votedid section, and get the 2 most voted ones. I also need,how many times they are voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bWpgdz-Gf53

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$votedid", votes: { $sum: 1 } } }, // group by voter id and get the no of votes
  { $sort: { votes: -1 } }, // sort by descending
  { $limit: 2 } // limit top 2 records
])
```